# Why the magic method '__get' has been called twice?

Tags: php

I have seen some code like below, and it is strange that the `__get` method has been called twice, why?

```
class Foo {
    private $bar;

    function __get($name){
        echo "__get is called!";
        return $this->$name;
    }

    function __unset($name){
        unset($this->$name);
    }
}
$foo = new Foo;
unset($foo->bar);
echo $foo->bar;
```

**Attention**: `unset($foo->bar)` will not call the `__get`.

Comment: Maybe it just reads it when instantiating the object to cache the fields in memory? Or it reads the field first before unsetting it? Does it hurt when it gets called twice? ;-)

Comment: @JonStirling `__get` has been called twice but not once.

Comment: @SebastianWramba So what is the reason?

Comment: by the way, this happens only when you use unset. Without unset it is called only once(the normal).

Comment: @Yousf I know that, so what happened after unset? :)

Comment: @xdazz, seems like php become upset after unset :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it looks like a bug. Put some debugging code (the following) and see the result:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    private $bar;

    function __get($name){
        echo "__get(".$name.") is called!\n";
        debug_print_backtrace();
        $x = $this->$name;
        return $x;
    }

    function __unset($name){
        unset($this->$name);

        echo "Value of ". $name ." After unsetting is \n";
        echo $this->$name;
        echo  "\n";
    }
}
echo "Before\n";
$foo = new Foo;
echo "After1\n";
unset($foo->bar);
echo "After2\n";
echo $foo->bar;
echo "After3\n";
echo $foo->not_found;
?>
```

The result is:

```
Before
After1
Value of bar After unsetting is
__get(bar) is called!
#0  Foo->__get(bar) called at [E:\temp\t1.php:17]
#1  Foo->__unset(bar) called at [E:\temp\t1.php:24]
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Foo::$bar in E:\temp\t1.php on line 9

After2
__get(bar) is called!
#0  Foo->__get(bar) called at [E:\temp\t1.php:26]
__get(bar) is called!
#0  Foo->__get(bar) called at [E:\temp\t1.php:9]
#1  Foo->__get(bar) called at [E:\temp\t1.php:26]
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Foo::$bar in E:\temp\t1.php on line 9
After3
__get(not_found) is called!
#0  Foo->__get(not_found) called at [E:\temp\t1.php:28]
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Foo::$not_found in E:\temp\t1.php on line 9
```

Answer (score 1):

invoked in

1)

```
 return $this->$name;
```

2)

```
 echo $foo->bar;
```

in the code:

```
    class Foo {
        private $bar;

        function __get($name){
            echo "__get is called!";
            return $this->$name;  *** here ***
        }

        function __unset($name){
            unset($this->$name);
        }
    }
    $foo = new Foo;
    unset($foo->bar);
    echo $foo->bar;   *** and here ***
```

**__get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.**

so, un-setting the variable, turn $foo->bar and $this->bar inaccessible. However, if unset is removed then $foo->bar is inaccessible but $this->bar is accessible.

However, i don't know how PHP avoid to call the function recursively. May be PHP is smart or the variable is self-setting at some point.

Comment: This does not help at all, it does not explain anything!?

Comment: __get method has been called twice, why?  because it is invoked twice.

Comment: Alright, now it's clear what you meant. Removed my downvote. But still not correct. You're saying that the getter calls himself when returning the variable, which would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, however php is enough smart for avoid it.  It is pretty easy to prove it, simple replace the return by another different value.

Comment: @magallanes So why __get is called just once if you `echo $foo->boo`? It is also happened that `$foo->boo` and `$this->boo` inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

The magic __get function is called everytime you try to access a variable. If you look at your code, you do this exactly 2 times. Once in the unset function and once in the echo function.

unset(***$foo->bar***);
echo ***$foo->bar***;

Comment: If you comment out the last line, you will know that `unset($foo->bar)` will not call the `__get` method.

Comment: This is not true, calling unset($foo->bar) doesn't trigger __get.

Comment: So only calling `unset` and `echo` in combination makes `__get` get called twice, whereas `echo` alone does trigger `__get`, but `unset` alone does not. This is rather funny.